# Databinding error in using TemplateField

Tags: asp.net

When run an asp.net page which containd the folloing code, I get "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PKComplexID'" error

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complex">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RefahiConnectionString1 %>"
             SelectCommand="SELECT [PKComplexID], [ComplexName] FROM RFH_Complex">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLComplex" runat="server" DataTextField="ComplexName" DataValueField="PKComplexID"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PKComplexID") %>' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ComplexName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using DetailsView and the DefaultMode = Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare the datasource control inside of the template; the `DropDownList` won't be able to find a datasource control with a matching ID.

Move the datasource control outside of the grid, and you should be all set.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. I get the same error. I have exactly the same code in another page. It is ok.

Comment: Post your updated code. On the other page, you have the datasource control nested in the item template and it's working?

Comment: I found the problem. Instead of PKComplexID I uesd FKComplexID that exists in the main sqlsatasource fields.